# How to use Tiny MCE's execCommand with jquery version

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have got probllems when loading tinymce text editors using fancybox. And answer has been pushed forwad by using

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'elm1');
```

to remove the tinymce instance.

my problem being that when using this it says tinyMCE is not defined yet all files are loaded in.

in the original version before the jquery version it is loaded using

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        ...
```

but in the jquery version there is none of that but there is

```
$('#elm1').tinymce({
```

can anyone tell my I am getting this error and how to over come this?

regards

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any problems if you use the standard build (not the jQuery one). We used the jQuery build till a few weeks ago, but found out that processing text input (typing, a.s.o.) is 4-6 times slower when using the tinymce jQuery build. Now, we load the standard jQuery librars (jquery.js) and the standard tinymce build(tiny_mce.js). This way tinymce is much faster and jQuery is available for use in custom plugins.